# Как преобразовать данный си код в JS?

Tags: javascript, c

Собственно, вот код

```
double data[][4]={
    0,  0,  0,  0,
    0,  0,  1,  1,
    0,  1,  0,  1,
    0,  1,  1,  0,
    1,  0,  0,  1,
    1,  0,  1,  0,
    1,  1,  0,  0,
    1,  1,  1,  1 
};
for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++){
    funct(data[i % 8], &data[i % 8][3]);
}
```

Comment: Взять и преобразовать, проблем-то?

Comment: Прочитать, как объявляются в JS массивы, перенести объявление массива `data`. Посмотреть, как в JS выглядит цикл `for`, удивиться, перенести цикл. Обнаружить, что функция `funct` нигде не объявлена, огорчиться.

Comment: Я понимаю еще, когда просят перенести в соседний язык, php - python или что-то такое. Но из низкоуровневого си в до-недавнего-времени-почти-исключительно-браузерный яваскрипт...

Comment: меня переклинело на си коде, двумерный массив который таковым не является (тут достаточно и одномерного) как вообще может передаваться что-то в функцию, ведь заполнен только один уровень массива

Comment: @Fangog: Вы что-то неправильно понимаете. Объявление выше - совершенно правильное объявление двумерного массива `double data[8][4]`. Заполнен этот массив тоже совершенно правильно, а никакой не "один уровень". В языке С не требуется делать вложенные уровни `{}` для инициализации более "глубоких" уровней вложенности агрегатов.

Comment: @Fangog: Что вы имеете в виду под "достаточно и одномерного" мне не совсем ясно. Любой многомерный массив можно, разумеется, "разложить" в одномерный. Но зачем? Данный код работает именно с двумерным массивом.

Comment: Я о том, что он инициализирован как одномерный. Если я вас правильно понял, то си автоматически заключает 4 значения в один уровень и не надо писать {}

Comment: @Fangog : Совершенно верно. Си автоматически "сворачивает" такой инициализатор, разрубая его на кусочки по 4 элемента и используя их для инициализации двумерного массива.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function funct(array, value) {
    console.log(array, value);
}

var data = [
    [0,  0,  0,  0],
    [0,  0,  1,  1],
    [0,  1,  0,  1],
    [0,  1,  1,  0],
    [1,  0,  0,  1],
    [1,  0,  1,  0],
    [1,  1,  0,  0],
    [1,  1,  1,  1] 
];

for (var i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
    var arr = data[i % 8];
    funct(arr, arr[3]);
}
```

Заполнить 2-х мерный массив data можно так:

```
function decbin(dec, length) {
    var result = [];
    while(length--) {
        result.push( (dec >> length ) & 1);    
    }
    return result;  
}

function binmatrix(arr) {
    var data = [];
    for (var i in arr) {
        data.push(decbin(arr[i], 4));
    }    
    return data;
}

var data = binmatrix([0,3,5,6,9,10,12,15]);
```